# How to fetch data from a class and transform result in JSON

Tags: php, laravel

I created a class "ZohoV2".

This class contains a function to retrieve data from a module of a CRM.

```
public function getUsers(){
    $bulkAPIResponse=ZCRMOrganization::getInstance()->getAllUsers();
    $users=$bulkAPIResponse->getData();
}
```

The function returns me the results when I do a `print_r($users)`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => zcrmsdk\crm\crud\ZCRMRecord Object
        (
            [entityId:zcrmsdk\crm\crud\ZCRMRecord:private] => 2076424000000355008
            [moduleApiName:zcrmsdk\crm\crud\ZCRMRecord:private] => Leads
            [lineItems:zcrmsdk\crm\crud\ZCRMRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [lookupLabel:zcrmsdk\crm\crud\ZCRMRecord:private] => 
            [owner:zcrmsdk\crm\crud\ZCRMRecord:private] => zcrmsdk\crm\setup\users\ZCRMUser Object
                (
                    [id:zcrmsdk\crm\setup\users\ZCRMUser:private] => 2076424000000104007
                    [name:zcrmsdk\crm\setup\users\ZCRMUser:private] => A-th Admin
                    [signature:zcrmsdk\crm\setup\users\ZCRMUser:private] => 
                    [country:zcrmsdk\crm\setup\users\ZCRMUser:private] => 
                    [role:zcrmsdk\crm\setup\users\ZCRMUser:private] => 
                    [customizeInfo:zcrmsdk\crm\setup\users\ZCRMUser:private] => 
                    [city:zcrmsdk\crm\setup\users\ZCRMUser:private] => 
                    [nameFormat:zcrmsdk\crm\setup\users\ZCRMUser:private] => 
                    [language:zcrmsdk\crm\setup\users\ZCRMUser:private] => 
                    [locale:zcrmsdk\crm\setup\users\ZCRMUser:private] => 
                    [isPersonalAccount:zcrmsdk\crm\setup\users\ZCRMUser:private] => 
                    …
```

The [documentation](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/get-users.html) requests to add this function to loop and display the data

```
foreach($users as $userInstance)
          {
          echo $userInstance->getCountry();
          $roleInstance=$userInstance->getRole();
          echo $roleInstance->getId();
          echo $roleInstance->getName();
          …
```

It works and it returns me the following result

```
2076424000000026008Employefr_FRfr_FRUSConsultantf.jerom@ith.comHH:mm2076424000000538017ConsultantIthEurope/London6372345901Ith Consultantdd/MM/yyyyactive2076424000000026005CEO1Salutation,Last Name,First Namefr_FRfr_FR0#FFFFFF#222222#FFFFFF#222222FRAdmininfo@Ith.comfr_BEHH:mm2076424000000026011Administrator0491078106A-thCET6334039531Ith Admin0491078106dd/MM/yyyyactive
```

I have a function `results()` that I call in my controller to display the data.

```
public function results()
{
    $obj = new ZohoV2();
    $obj->getUsers();

}
```

I do not know how to exploit this data. This is the first time I play with an API.

How to transform the results into JSON for example? And have a result like this? (The [documentation](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/get-users.html) shows this as an expected result but me, with their code, I have the table that I showed you above)

```
{
"users": [
   {
        "country": null,
        "role": {
            "name": "CEO",
            "id": "2445013000000026005"
        },
        "city": null,
        "signature": null,
```

Big thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use serialization: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

return $user->toJson();

return $user->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```